# Do you use a comma when the object comes before the subject?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Would you use a comma after the object in a sentence where the predicate comes before the subject?

For example, if the sentence is "**One friend I saw.**", would you put a comma after the word friend?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you have fronted the object. You can use a comma to separate the object from the subject and the verb, however this is very archaic and isn't used often in newer English. If you really wanted to, use the comma but take into account that some may not understand the focus being on the object and not on the subject and noun.

Comment: It also depends a lot on the context. Is this actual speech, is it a title, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  So if I understand correctly, are you saying that really there should be no comma?  I didn't follow what you were trying to say in your last sentence.  Thank you!